# Rails - only fetch certain params in controller method

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've got a custom action called 'contact' in the users controller. This action will be accessed by a guest account, who has read only access to some things that user sets up. The view should display only certain attributes of the user - for example their name, and not their more private details. I'm using CanCan & Devise for authentication & authorisation.

I've got name, password etc. set as an attr_accessible in the user model. So, my question is, what is to stop a guest from accessing all of the attributes of the user they are linked to? My 'contact' view only has @user.name - is there any way of a hacker refreshing the page with e.g. @user.private_details, or is that not possible?

If it is possible, how do I counteract this - is there a way that I can change the controller action to only call certain params from the database, e.g:

```
@user = User.find(params[:id]), :only => (:first_name, :last_name)
```

Any advice would be much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An attacker has no way of controlling which template is used for a response (unless possibly your controller switches which template is used based on user input)

They could however request the response in a different format, for example they could ask for a JSON representation of the document, which a scaffolded rails show action would respond to. You can of course override what json is returned.

Lastly to answer the original question, `select` allows you to control what is fetched from the database, for example

```
User.select(:first_name, :last_name).find(params[:id])
```

Comment: Thanks for that, however, it is giving me the error "wrong number of arguments (3 for 1)" with the following line - any ideas? Thanks.      @user = User.select(:first_name, :last_name, :email).find(params[:id])

Comment: I found the answer - it's slightly different syntax - User.select("first_name, last_name").find(params[:id]) - thanks for pointing me to the answer, and for the extra info!